# Convert byte[] to PDF Sharp Document and Email as Attachment

Tags: c#, pdf, arrays, email-attachments

I am using the PDF Sharp library to create a custom PDF. I want to be able to email this custom PDF as an attachment without saving a local copy first. The way I am trying to achieve this is by converting the generated PDF Sharp document to a byte array as follows:

```
byte[] pdfBuffer = null;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  document.Save(ms, false);

  pdfBuffer = ms.ToArray();
}
```

This part seems to be working,  however the part I am hving problems with is converting the byte array back a PDF file. With the code below the PDF is being attached to the email but when the attachment is opened it is a blank file. This is the code I am using to do that:

```
//Add PDF attachment.
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(attachmentData);

mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, attachmentFilename, "application/pdf"));

//Setup up SMTP details.
smtpClient = new SmtpClient("************.com");
smtpUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****@****.com", "*****", "*****.com");
smtpClient.Credentials = smtpUserInfo;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

//Send the email.
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Can anyone please explain a correct way of converting the PDF stream back to a valid PDF and send is an email attachment?

Comment: Google "C# convert byte[] to pdf" - all you need to know should be in first 3 links.

Comment: Have you checked you are actually sending the correct pdf stream to email? One way of doing this (just for testing) would be to save it locally and send in email.

Comment: I have checked the PDF by saving locally at it seems fine.

Comment: OK I looked into some links and I can't find anyway of converting the stream to a `System.IO.File` object without saving it the hard drive. Is there a way to recreate the PDF using only memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the document was appearing blank when I converted the stream back to a PDF is that when using `document.Save(memoryStream, false);`, it is neccessary to call `document.Close();` after, i.e.:

```
document.Save(memoryStream, false);
document.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            WebClient User = new WebClient();
            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(strPDFPath);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(FileBuffer);
            ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
            pdf = new Attachment(stream, ct);
            pdf.ContentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
            msg.Attachments.Add(pdf);
            pdf.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(strPDFPath);
```